# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class net.ma.soap.ws.entities.App

Tags: java, xml, spring, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy a web application in **wildfly 8.2** but i keep getting the same exception, **IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type**, tomcat deploys the app just fine.

These are my config files

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>net.ma</groupId>
        <artifactId>soap</artifactId>
        <name>SOAP-SERVER</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <properties>
            <java-version>1.8</java-version>
            <org.springframework-version>4.1.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
            <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
            <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
            <cxf.version>3.1.4</cxf.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- AspectJ -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.15</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- @Inject -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.7</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- CXF Framework -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.34</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <additionalBuildcommands>
                            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                        </additionalBuildcommands>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">


        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
        <context:component-scan base-package="net.ma.soap.ws.*"/>
        <jpa:repositories base-package="net.ma.soap.ws.dao"></jpa:repositories>

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">    <!-- La création du datasource -->
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test20"></property>
            <property name="username" value="root"></property>
            <property name="password" value=""></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MY_P"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                                     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
                                     version="1.0">

                <persistence-unit name="MY_P" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
                    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                    <properties>
                        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
                        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
                    </properties>
                </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

**App.java**

```
    package net.ma.soap.ws.entities;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;

    import net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.annotation.constraint.NotEmpty;

    @Entity
    public class App {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long idApp;

        @Column(length = 20)
        @NotEmpty
        private String appToken;

        @Column(length = 35)
        @NotEmpty
        private String appName;

        public App() {
            super();
        }

        public App(String appName) {
            super();
            this.appName = appName;
        }

        public Long getIdApp() {
            return idApp;
        }

        public void setIdApp(Long idApp) {
            this.idApp = idApp;
        }

        public String getAppToken() {
            return appToken;
        }

        public void setAppToken(String appToken) {
            this.appToken = appToken;
        }

        public String getAppName() {
            return appName;
        }

        public void setAppName(String appName) {
            this.appName = appName;
        }
    }
```

**Exception Trace**

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class net.ma.soap.ws.entities.App
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:146)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:90)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:70)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:170)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
        ... 47 more
```

I've been looking for answers to some similar problems but nothing worked, i really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Persistence XML:

```
<persistence-unit name="MY_P" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
     <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>  <!-- This line -->
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```